# display content of a .js file called asynchronously in AIR

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, air

I am new to AIR programming and find there is a lack of useful debug tools. For instance, a JSONP request works fine in HTTP but not in the AIR app generated.

Basically, I am creating a "script" element, giving him an URL as "src" and appending it to "head". But I don't have expected results and would like to know what is the content of the "src" returned through this call.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User a URLRequest to load the js without executing it - see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLRequest.html